# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function.. check the render method of

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to import my NavigationBar component to my React App.

My NavigationBar.js:

```js
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-pascal-case */

import React from 'react';

import {Nav, Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styles = styled.div`
.navbar {
    background-color: #222;

}

a, .navbar-brand, .navbar-nav, .nav-link {
    color: #bbb;

    &:hover { color:white 
}
}


`;

export const NavigationBar = () => (

    <Styles>
        <Navbar expand="lg">
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Code Life</Navbar.Brand>
           <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
           <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav"> 
           <Nav className="ml-auto">
               <Nav.item><Nav.link href="/">Home</Nav.link></Nav.item>
               <Nav.item><Nav.link href="/About">Home</Nav.link></Nav.item>
               <Nav.item><Nav.link href="/Contact">Contact</Nav.link></Nav.item>
           </Nav>
           
           </Navbar.Collapse>

        </Navbar>
    </Styles>

)
```

My App.js-file

```js
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-pascal-case */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Home} from './Home';
import {About} from './About';
import {Contact} from './Contact';
import {NoMatch} from './NoMatch';
import {Layout} from './components/Layout';
import {NavigationBar} from './components/NavigationBar'

 
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavigationBar />
        <Layout>
        <Router>
         
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
        
        </Router>
        </Layout>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get the following error when trying to access my react project in the browser.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `NavigationBar`.

What exactly do I have to check? There is no render method in NavigationBar.js